# Joining Postgres BDR Node Uses Outdated DSN

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-bdr

I have a cluster of Postgres BDR that has 3 nodes "[Ready](http://bdr-project.org/docs/0.9.0/catalog-bdr-nodes.html)" and 3 nodes "[Parted](http://bdr-project.org/docs/0.9.0/catalog-bdr-nodes.html)".

If I do `SELECT * FROM bdr.bdr_nodes` the following information is displayed:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------+-------------------------
node_sysid         | 6153716379158074503
node_timeline      | 1
node_dboid         | 16385
node_status        | r
node_name          | node3
node_local_dsn     | host=x.x.x.241 [...]
node_init_from_dsn | host=x.x.x.47 [...]
-[ RECORD 2 ]------+-------------------------
node_sysid         | 6153716914784688297
node_timeline      | 1
node_dboid         | 16385
node_status        | r
node_name          | node2
node_local_dsn     | host=x.x.x.5 [...]
node_init_from_dsn | host=x.x.x.47 [...]
-[ RECORD 3 ]------+-------------------------
node_sysid         | 6170758438846557459
node_timeline      | 1
node_dboid         | 16384
node_status        | r
node_name          | node4
node_local_dsn     | host=x.x.x.128 [...]
node_init_from_dsn | host=x.x.x.47 [...]
-[ RECORD 4 ]------+-------------------------
node_sysid         | 6153716402564903569
node_timeline      | 1
node_dboid         | 16385
node_status        | k
node_name          | node1
node_local_dsn     | host=x.x.x.47 [...]
node_init_from_dsn | 
-[ RECORD 5 ]------+-------------------------
node_sysid         | 6170830020100809103
node_timeline      | 1
node_dboid         | 16385
node_status        | k
node_name          | node6
node_local_dsn     | host=x.x.x.48 [...]
node_init_from_dsn | host=x.x.x.241 [...]
-[ RECORD 6 ]------+-------------------------
node_sysid         | 6170839982079996801
node_timeline      | 1
node_dboid         | 16385
node_status        | c
node_name          | node8
node_local_dsn     | host=x.x.x.142 [...]
node_init_from_dsn | host=x.x.x.241 [...]
-[ RECORD 7 ]------+-------------------------
node_sysid         | 6170833985333433816
node_timeline      | 1
node_dboid         | 16385
node_status        | k
node_name          | node7
node_local_dsn     | host=x.x.x.48 [...]
node_init_from_dsn | host=x.x.x.241 [...]
```

I am trying to join `node8`. But it just won't happen. The error is the following:

```
d= p=5521 a=ERROR:  08006: could not connect to the primary server: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
        Is the server running on host "x.x.x.48" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
d= p=5521 a=DETAIL:  Connection string is 'host=x.x.x.48 [...]'
```

That error means that it is trying to connect to a node that has been killed or removed. Why is trying to connect to a node that is killed or removed ? How can I fix this situation ?

The following command was used to join `node8`

```
SELECT bdr.bdr_group_join(
      local_node_name := 'node8',
      node_external_dsn := 'host=x.x.x.142 [...]',
      join_using_dsn := 'host=x.x.x.241 [...]'
);
```

BDR has been installed according to [this instructions](https://manageacloud.com/configuration/postgresql-bdr) (Debian Wheezy):

```
curl -sSL https://manageacloud.com/api/cm/configuration/postgresql-bdr/debian/manageacloud-production-script.sh | bash
```

Table `bdr.bdr_connections`:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]----------+---------------------
conn_sysid             | 6170839982079996801
conn_timeline          | 1
conn_dboid             | 16385
conn_origin_sysid      | 0
conn_origin_timeline   | 0
conn_origin_dboid      | 0
conn_is_unidirectional | f
conn_dsn               | host=x.x.x.142 [...]
conn_apply_delay       | 
conn_replication_sets  | {default}
-[ RECORD 2 ]----------+----------------------
conn_sysid             | 6153716402564903569
conn_timeline          | 1
conn_dboid             | 16385
conn_origin_sysid      | 0
conn_origin_timeline   | 0
conn_origin_dboid      | 0
conn_is_unidirectional | f
conn_dsn               | host=x.x.x.47 [...]
conn_apply_delay       | 
conn_replication_sets  | {default}
-[ RECORD 3 ]----------+-----------------------
conn_sysid             | 6153716379158074503
conn_timeline          | 1
conn_dboid             | 16385
conn_origin_sysid      | 0
conn_origin_timeline   | 0
conn_origin_dboid      | 0
conn_is_unidirectional | f
conn_dsn               | host=x.x.x.241 [...]
conn_apply_delay       | 
conn_replication_sets  | {default}
-[ RECORD 4 ]----------+-----------------------
conn_sysid             | 6153716914784688297
conn_timeline          | 1
conn_dboid             | 16385
conn_origin_sysid      | 0
conn_origin_timeline   | 0
conn_origin_dboid      | 0
conn_is_unidirectional | f
conn_dsn               | host=x.x.x.5 [...]
conn_apply_delay       | 
conn_replication_sets  | {default}
-[ RECORD 5 ]----------+-----------------------
conn_sysid             | 6170758438846557459
conn_timeline          | 1
conn_dboid             | 16384
conn_origin_sysid      | 0
conn_origin_timeline   | 0
conn_origin_dboid      | 0
conn_is_unidirectional | f
conn_dsn               | host=x.x.x.128 [...]
conn_apply_delay       | 
conn_replication_sets  | {default}
```

Version:

```
# SELECT bdr.bdr_version();
    bdr_version    
-------------------
 0.9.1-2015-05-26-
(1 row)
```

Comment: Please show your `bdr.bdr_connections` on the node you're joining using, .241. A peer will never connect to the `node_local_dsn` from `bdr.bdr_nodes`, that's only used for connection-to-self during initial data loading. Also please show the output of `SELECT bdr.bdr_version()`.

Comment: @CraigRinger added version and bdr_connections

Comment: @CraigRinger I just made a test, deleting the wrong "connections" from `bdr.bdr_connections` table solves the problem. Is this safe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in BDR. I've just fixed it in my local copy of the `bdr-plugin/next` tree and will push the change to `bdr-plugin/REL0_9_STABLE` for inclusion in 0.9.3 once I've tested it locally.

The issue is that we weren't filtering out `bdr.bdr_connections` rows based on the `bdr.bdr_nodes.state` during creation of slots on peers as part of node join.

It is safe to delete any `bdr.bdr_connections` entry with no corresponding `bdr.bdr_nodes` entry, or where the `bdr.bdr_nodes` entry has `state = 'k'` to work around this in 0.9.2 and older.